# Stream Example Nodejs - error when deploying to Heroku

Tags: node.js, getstream-io

I deployed this example on Heroku:
*https://github.com/GetStream/Stream-Example-Nodejs*

And I got this error:

```js
*016-12-15T15:12:54.464271+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=xxxxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx fwd="xxx.xx.xxx.x" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= $heroku run rails console*
```

According to Heroku, it's related to the file static/js/getstream.js, on this line of code:
*var f = path[name];
  assert.strictEqual(typeof f, "function");*

Anyone knows what is wrong?

Log:

```js
2016-12-13T18:16:04.228960+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2016-12-13T18:16:04.228961+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2016-12-13T18:16:04.228961+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2016-12-13T18:16:04.228962+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)
2016-12-13T18:16:04.228963+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2016-12-13T23:52:20.137216+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-12-13T23:52:47.313194+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node build/bundle/main.js`
2016-12-13T23:52:49.511615+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2016-12-13T23:52:49.531574+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-12-13T23:52:49.416509+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-12-13T23:52:49.416749+00:00 app[web.1]: assert.js:93
2016-12-13T23:52:49.416962+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw new assert.AssertionError({
2016-12-13T23:52:49.416964+00:00 app[web.1]:         ^
2016-12-13T23:52:49.418475+00:00 app[web.1]: AssertionError: "undefined" === "function"
2016-12-13T23:52:49.418477+00:00 app[web.1]:     at wrapPathFunction (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:77:10)
2016-12-13T23:52:49.418478+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)
2016-12-13T23:52:49.418479+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2016-12-13T23:52:49.418480+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2016-12-13T23:52:49.418480+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2016-12-13T23:52:49.418481+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2016-12-13T23:52:49.418481+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2016-12-13T23:52:49.418482+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2016-12-13T23:52:49.418482+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)
2016-12-13T23:52:49.418483+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2016-12-14T06:00:54.566563+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-12-14T06:01:29.273461+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node build/bundle/main.js`
2016-12-14T06:01:32.783653+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2016-12-14T06:01:32.772485+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-12-14T06:01:32.673024+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-12-14T06:01:32.673552+00:00 app[web.1]: assert.js:93
2016-12-14T06:01:32.673919+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw new assert.AssertionError({
2016-12-14T06:01:32.674014+00:00 app[web.1]:         ^
2016-12-14T06:01:32.676573+00:00 app[web.1]: AssertionError: "undefined" === "function"
2016-12-14T06:01:32.676575+00:00 app[web.1]:     at wrapPathFunction (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:77:10)
2016-12-14T06:01:32.676576+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)
2016-12-14T06:01:32.676577+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2016-12-14T06:01:32.676578+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2016-12-14T06:01:32.676578+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2016-12-14T06:01:32.676579+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2016-12-14T06:01:32.676580+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2016-12-14T06:01:32.676581+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2016-12-14T06:01:32.676582+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)
2016-12-14T06:01:32.676582+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2016-12-14T11:37:40.339409+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-12-14T11:38:03.978887+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node build/bundle/main.js`
2016-12-14T11:38:07.913864+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-12-14T11:38:07.924133+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2016-12-14T11:38:07.656236+00:00 app[web.1]: assert.js:93
2016-12-14T11:38:07.655813+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-12-14T11:38:07.656601+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw new assert.AssertionError({
2016-12-14T11:38:07.656605+00:00 app[web.1]:         ^
2016-12-14T11:38:07.659083+00:00 app[web.1]: AssertionError: "undefined" === "function"
2016-12-14T11:38:07.659085+00:00 app[web.1]:     at wrapPathFunction (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:77:10)
2016-12-14T11:38:07.659086+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)
2016-12-14T11:38:07.659086+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2016-12-14T11:38:07.659087+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2016-12-14T11:38:07.659087+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2016-12-14T11:38:07.659088+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2016-12-14T11:38:07.659089+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2016-12-14T11:38:07.659089+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2016-12-14T11:38:07.659090+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)
2016-12-14T11:38:07.659091+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2016-12-14T17:14:14.734371+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-12-14T17:14:32.543524+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node build/bundle/main.js`
2016-12-14T17:14:34.125551+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-12-14T17:14:34.109446+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2016-12-14T17:14:34.038976+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-12-14T17:14:34.039214+00:00 app[web.1]: assert.js:93
2016-12-14T17:14:34.039443+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw new assert.AssertionError({
2016-12-14T17:14:34.039445+00:00 app[web.1]:         ^
2016-12-14T17:14:34.040928+00:00 app[web.1]: AssertionError: "undefined" === "function"
2016-12-14T17:14:34.040929+00:00 app[web.1]:     at wrapPathFunction (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:77:10)
2016-12-14T17:14:34.040930+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)
2016-12-14T17:14:34.040930+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2016-12-14T17:14:34.040931+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2016-12-14T17:14:34.040931+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2016-12-14T17:14:34.040932+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2016-12-14T17:14:34.040932+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2016-12-14T17:14:34.040933+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2016-12-14T17:14:34.040933+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2016-12-14T17:14:34.040933+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)
2016-12-14T23:06:38.755453+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-12-14T23:06:58.761174+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node build/bundle/main.js`
2016-12-14T23:07:01.705888+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-12-14T23:07:01.680683+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2016-12-14T23:07:01.585225+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-12-14T23:07:01.585483+00:00 app[web.1]: assert.js:93
2016-12-14T23:07:01.585692+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw new assert.AssertionError({
2016-12-14T23:07:01.585696+00:00 app[web.1]:         ^
2016-12-14T23:07:01.587139+00:00 app[web.1]: AssertionError: "undefined" === "function"
2016-12-14T23:07:01.587157+00:00 app[web.1]:     at wrapPathFunction (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:77:10)
2016-12-14T23:07:01.587158+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)
2016-12-14T23:07:01.587159+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2016-12-14T23:07:01.587159+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2016-12-14T23:07:01.587160+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2016-12-14T23:07:01.587161+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2016-12-14T23:07:01.587161+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2016-12-14T23:07:01.587162+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2016-12-14T23:07:01.587163+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)
2016-12-14T23:07:01.587164+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2016-12-15T15:12:54.464271+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=xxxxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx fwd="xxx.xx.xxx.x" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    $heroku run rails console
```

Comment: You should include what the error is as we can't possibly know what it is otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, added now! ; )